# Uploading several images to firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload several images to firebase storage.
I have written following code for this :-

```
    private static void uploadImage(String imageUrl)
    {
        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        final StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://image-store.appspot.com/");
        Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File(imageUrl));
        String imageName = System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg"; 
        StorageReference imageRef = storageRef.child("images").child(imageName);
        UploadTask uploadTask = imageRef.putFile(file);
    }

    private static uploadImages(String[] imageUrls)
    {
        for(imageUrl : imageUrls)
        {
            uploadImage(imageUrl)
        }
    }
```

When there are fewer images to upload, the above code works fine. But when there are around a 100+ images it creates several asynchronous threads and gives the following error:-

```
Exception java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$5@ef10d00 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1c98b939[Running, pool size = 2, active threads = 2, queued tasks = 128, completed tasks = 59]
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2042)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:796)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1370)
com.google.firebase.storage.zzd.zzu ()
com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.schedule ()
com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.an ()
com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.putFile ()
com.indiacom.blanketfos.util.FirebaseUtil.uploadImage (FirebaseUtil.java:64)
com.indiacom.blanketfos.util.FirebaseUtil.uploadImages (FirebaseUtil.java:126)
com.indiacom.blanketfos.util.FirebaseUtil.syncRealmToFirebase (FirebaseUtil.java:33)
com.indiacom.blanketfos.ui.FormActivity.onOptionsItemSelected (FormActivity.java:406)
android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected (Activity.java:2983)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected (FragmentActivity.java:408)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected (AppCompatActivity.java:195)
android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected (WindowCallbackWrapper.java:113)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onMenuItemSelected (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:675)
android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected (MenuBuilder.java:822)
android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke (MenuItemImpl.java:156)
android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction (MenuBuilder.java:969)
android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction (MenuBuilder.java:959)
android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem (ActionMenuView.java:623)
android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick (ActionMenuItemView.java:154)
android.view.View.performClick (View.java:4781)
android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:19907)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:160)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5541)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:964)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:759)
```

So my question is what is the best and the most efficient way of uploading several images to firebase storage without landing into such problems.

Comment: Uploading 100 images in parallel sounds like a bad idea. I'd use a more reasonable number of parallel uploads (say 3-5) and only start a new upload, once one of the existing ones completes (you can [monitor progress from the upload task](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress)).

Comment: If you limit your Executor to only the number of cores on the device, say 4, then it works. But this makes everything much slower of course. Posting to Firebase realtime database is OK, but I guess this is very fast, while uploading is slow and grabs a thread. Maybe you should only start a new runnabletask in the executor once all the UploadTasks have completed?

Comment: Use addOnCompleteListener to send an empty message to your Handler, so it restarts the download/upload. This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was having same problem and found out Firebase storage only accept max 100 concurrent upload for free account. So here is what I did and hope it helps:

```
private static void uploadFS(final File[] files, final StorageReference certRef, int startIndex, int concurrent) {
    int cnt = 0;
    File file;
    Uri uriFile;
    StorageReference ref;
    while (cnt < concurrent) {
        file = files[startIndex];
        startIndex++;
        if (file.exists() && file.length() > 0) { // local cert file exits
            uriFile = Uri.fromFile(file);
            final int sIdx = startIndex;
            ref = certRef.child("cert/" + uriFile.getLastPathSegment());
            ref.putFile(uriFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    uploadFS(files, certRef, sIdx, 1);
                }
            });
        }
        cnt++;
    }
}
public static void uploadCert() {
    StorageReference rootStorageRef = getStorageRefRoot();
    if (rootStorageRef != null) { // loop through download folder
        File certFolder = new File(MainActivity.DOWNLOAD_FULL_PATH + "cert/");
        if (certFolder.isDirectory()) {
            File[] certFiles = certFolder.listFiles();
            uploadFS(certFiles, rootStorageRef, 0, 3);  // 3 is concurrent upload tasks
        }
    }
}
```